# Defining Backbone.Layout as require js module?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I can't definie [tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager) layouts as requirejs modules. I'm pretty new to this and not a guru in javascript. `Backbone.Layout` is defined [at this line of source code](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/backbone.layoutmanager.js#L680). Ayway...

**First try**:

```js
define([
    'backbone',
    'lodash',
    'backbone.layoutmanager'
], function (Backbone, _) {

    return Backbone.Layout({
        template: 'body'
    });

});
```

Using the module in another one (main):

```js
var layout = new ApplicationLayout();
$('body').empty().append(layout.el);

layout.render();
```

Gives me (?!?):

> TypeError: this._configure is not a function
>
> this._configure(options || {});

**Second try** (note `new`):

```js
define([
    'backbone',
    'lodash',
    'backbone.layoutmanager'
], function (Backbone, _) {

    return new Backbone.Layout({
        template: 'body'
    });

});
```

Using in another module (always the main one):

```js
$('body').empty().append(ApplicationLayout.el);
ApplicationLayout.render();
```

Doesn't work, meaning that html is not injected in `<body>`. Seems that the only way to get this work is to create and render the layout in the same place, main module:

```js
var layout = Backbone.layout({ template: 'body' });
$('body').empty().append(layout.el);

layout.render();
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an argument for the layout manager in order to use it, e.g.

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'lodash',
    'backbone.layoutmanager'
], function (Backbone, _, Layout) {
return Layout({
    template: 'body'
});
```